# Python programs communicating

Tags: python, controls, communication

I have a (probably) simple question that the internet seems to be of no help with. I would like to make several python programs interact within another python program and have no idea how to get them to put input into each other. My eventual idea is to (as a proof of concept) have one program act as the environment and the others act as creatures in that environment. let me clarify: I am sure you have seen those programs that simulate natural environments with the creatures in them interacting. I would like to do the same kind of thing just on a smaller scale (text in the place of fancy 3d graphics if at all). The ultimate goal of this is not to have a complex ecosystem but to see how far I can push the communication between the programs (and my computer's power along the way). 
P.S. I would like to continue to run it from the IDLE or from the command line.

Comment: Have a look at the subprocess module

Comment: There are many ways that processes can communicate. You might find [zeromq](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all) a nice way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply setup a module structure. For example, write a `main.py` which either calls or imports data from the other "programs".

I would use an objected-oriented approach in your case.

For example if you have your programs setup as follows:

`main.py`
`prog1.py`
etc.

I would create a `main.py` e.g., like

```
import prog1
creature_obj = prog1.new_creature() # where new_creature is a class in prog1
...
```

Comment: Ok so I think this is the way I would like to do it but I don't know how to make the `prog1.py` available to the `main.py`. Could you explain that or post a link to a YouTube video? I don't have much experience with this kind of thing yet.

Comment: I get the `import prog1` part just not the stuff before that.

Comment: Actually, never mind. I used this site:  [http://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/making-modules.html] and figured it out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of choices for exhanging messages between programs or components:

1. You can write output files that other programs can read and act on.  You'd like to see if the consumer could watch a directory for a file and react when it arrived.
2. You could make them distributed components that exchanged messages via sockets or some higher level protocol like HTTP.  The communication could be synchronous or asynchronous.
3. You could connect them as producers writing to message queues or topics and consumers listening to the queue or topic for events.